# For Loop Error using an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am creating a simple program that will print the first and last names of my array of objects name students. When I run the program it prints all the names correctly but also states there is the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var students = [ 
     {first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'},
     {first_name: 'John', last_name : 'Rosales'},
     {first_name: 'Mark', last_name : 'Guillen'},
     {first_name: 'KB', last_name : 'Tonel'}
]

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    console.log(students[i].first_name + " " + students[i].last_name);
};
```

Is there an error in my for loop that I am not seeing?

Comment: Yes, if you start at zero, the last item in the array is three. When you get to four in the loop, you have `undefined` as there aren't that many items in your array.

Comment: You only have four object, your termination condition should be `i<4` inside for loop

Comment: you have an array of objects, so u also can use forEach()

Comment: Never ever ever ever use static lengths for iterating arrays. Always refer to *array.length*

Comment: @Jonasw 100% agrees cuz we never know if the length of array will be changed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will use .length from now on instead of static numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use i < 4, instead of <=.  You're hitting an undefined section of the array students[4].  A better practice would be to run your for loop for the number of items in the array.  such as for(var i =0; i < students.length; i++)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is iterating 5 times from  index(0-4). You only have 4 names. So it is trying to read a 5th element and is finding an undefined element.

**Change your for-loop to:**

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log(students[i].first_name + " " + students[i].last_name);
};
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with `i <= 3` but `i < students.length` would be better answer. What if the number of element in `students` array changes?

Answer (score 0):

Always remember array always starts it's index from 0 so in your case it will start like i=0 and as you have conditioned your loop till i<=4 it will point to null at i=4 so it will generate error so you can approach either of the two listed below

**End your loop to i=3**

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
console.log(students[i].first_name + " " + students[i].last_name);};
```

**Or start your loop from i=1 to i=4**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    console.log(students[i].first_name + " " + students[i].last_name);
};
```

The only thing that matters is the the number of time your for loop iterates and it shoudn't exceed your array's length.

Comment: when loop through an array, the best is user array.length, no a static number cuz array length could be change over time

Answer (score 0):

When you want to go through an array you can also use forEach like this:

```
students.forEach(function(student){
    console.log(student.first_name + " " + student.last_name);
});
```